# Building JSON from a list of organised words? NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, nodes

Excuse the terrible title, I have this as an example: 
The numbers represent how similar the word is compared to the search term.

```
0.3333333333333333: Jerome
0: Murphy
0: Louis
0.14285714285714285: Chester
0.2: Judah
0.125: Fletcher
0.14285714285714285: Gregory
0.16666666666666666: Daniel
0: Orson
0.16666666666666666: Rafael
0: Nasim
0: Tarik
0.16666666666666666: Daniel
0.25: Dale
0: Mannix
0: Dolan
0.14285714285714285: Bernard
0: Ethan
0: Brody
0.2: Arden
```

I tried to do this, 
Stage is from the

```
 for (Stage in results) {    

 var organisedsearch = 
      {
         "Name"  : results[Stage].Name,
         "Number" : Similarity
      }
  }
```

results is from a mysql query, Name is from the database.

but that gives this, 
Shortened example.

```
{"Number":0.3333333333333333}
{"Number":0.16666666666666666}
```

it also only returns the first line in the list, when I try to print it out of the loop, how can I put it into JSON?

What I would  like to achieve:

```
 {

  "Name":"Jerome",
  "RelevanceToSearch": 0.3"

 }
```

Repeated for each word/number in the list.

Comment: what are the field names of the person's name and the number?

Comment: What is `results`, what is `Stage`, what is `Similarity` ?

Comment: please add the source array/object in literal notation.

Comment: Similarity is from a algorithm I performed to check how similar each result is to the provided search term, it is all the numbers before each word at the top. 0.11:foo

Comment: You need first of all to clearly define your dataset (delimiters ), keys (name), etc. For example, what separates two rows of data (comma? space? Return key?) or what's the data structure (json file? .CSV?).

Answer (score 0):

You could map the data, if you have them in an array with objects and a name property.

```js
function similarity(name) {
    return Math.random(); // a dummy value
}

var data = [{ name: 'Jane' }, { name: 'Mary' }, { name: 'Lou' }, { name: 'Betty' }];
    result = data.map(function (object) {
        return {
            name: object.name,
            relevance: similarity(object.name)
        };
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```